# safari, minified js, Kendo UI script loading - getting 404s for sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

when my page loads, I'm getting tons of 404 errors for js sources I'm not even using. But they appear to be referenced from kendo.web.min.js and other kendo js scripts

All of my scripts are in:

/data/js/jquery_lib/

I'm loading up kendo.web.min.js

```
<link href="/data/css/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/data/css/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/data/css/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/jquery_lib/jquery.min.js"></script> (version 1.9.1)
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/jquery_lib/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

and this is what happens:

[image: list of 404s]
[image: safari developer resources list showing how minified kendo js is trying to load dependency sources]

Comment: what happened before these errors occurred? Sometimes errors in my code put me in similar situation.

Comment: Also checking the error url refer to `/data/js/src/js/` not `/data/js/jquery_lib/` make sure putting your files in correct path.